# c4 cycle in photosynthesis occurs in monocots or dicots

Tags: photosynthesis

the biosynthetic  portion of the c4 cycle occurs in the bundle sheath cells and i have studies that bundle sheath cells are present only in dicots and not monocots.
according to this, the c4 cycle shold be occuring in dicots and not monocots (due to the absence of bundle s. cells).
but important examples of pants following the c4 pathway like maize and sorghum are monocots.

i dont understand if there is a confusion on my side regarding presence of bs cells in dicots or if there is somewhere else that im going wrong.[the following link is contradicting my answer as to presnce of bs cells in dicots](https://www.quora.com/Does-a-dicot-leaf-possess-bundle-sheath-cells/answer/Kiran-Jajula)

Comment: I had the same confusion but monocots do not lack bundle sheath cells.

Answer (score 1):

monocots don't lack bundle sheath cells.  In fact, they are much *more* likely use c4 respiration than dicots.  There are actually about 10 times more c4 monocot species than c4 dicot species.  the c4 cycle is really primarily a monocot adaptation.  I think that the confusion often comes from the fact that dicots appear to be "more sophisticated" than monocots when you look at them, with their pretty, well organized vascular bundles and branching veins, which makes it intuitive to assume that they would be the ones using the "higher tech" c4 system.

Answer (score 0):

C4 photosynthesis occurs in bundle sheath cells. And bundle sheath cells are present in dicots as well as in monocots. But anatomy is different in both types.

The bundle sheath in dicot leaf is present in single layer and made of colorless cells. On other hand in monocot, the bundle sheath is made up of single or double layer and made of colored cells because of chloroplasts.

The bundle sheath of dicot leaf is made of parenchyma cells whereas the bundle sheath in monocot leaf consists of sclerenchyma cells.

(Via:  https://vivadifferences.com/monocot-leaf-vs-dicot-leaf/)